# Creating Folder in Android Custom Rom

Tags: android

I'm building an Android custom ROM with an additional logging mechanism for a research project. My customized Android source code contains file logging via `PrintWriter(filename)`. So far it works fine, but now I want to be able to grab its output from a concurrently developed App.

The problem is: When the PrintWriter creates the a new log file, it is created with `rw-------` permission and so I'm not able to read the file from my App. What would be the best way to make that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself. It works with the java methods of the File class, but you have to invoke these **after** actually creating the file, which is in my opinion not straightforward, because I expected it to work like setting some attributes and then actually creating the file with these specified attributes. Here is an example of setting Read/Write/Execute permissions for everyone for a specific file:

```
File file = new File("logs/log.txt");
file.createNewFile();
file.setWritable(true, false);
file.setReadable(true, false);
file.setExecutable(true, false);
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
```